# How to calculate month between two dates in stata

Tags: stata, data-analysis, data-science

I want to create a variable with the age of credit. The data only has the date of the start of credit.

I create date variable (eg 2017-12-31) for default. Then, i want calculate age with date of the start credit.

I tried to search for an article about that, but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this beyond it being about dates somehow. I suggest  (please) (a) giving a worked example with data you have and data you want (b) asking a friend with better command of English to rewrite: it's not grammatical or idiomatic.  Use `dataex` (`ssc inst dataex`). Assuming that people work with finance data is not recommended; assume no specialist knowledge beyond expertise in Stata.

Comment: On second go, I note that age is the difference between two dates, e.g. 2017 - 1917 = 100. I don't know if that helps enough. You mention both months and a daily date 2017-12-31 so what you have as your data isn't yet clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your data is daily. In that case what you need is:

```
gen current_date=date("20171231","YMD")
format current_date %td //this will be the variable from which age will be calculated
gen age=current_date-start_credit_date //again, assuming the start credit variable is daily
```

this gives the age variable as the number of days. If you want it as the number of months, you need to add:

```
gen current_month=mofd(current_date)
format current_month %tm
gen start_month=mofd(start_credit_date)
format start_month %tm
gen age_month=current_month-start_month
```

Comment: Helpful. You need a `gen` in front of `start_month`.